# java jsp display data from database

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, tomcat, web.xml

Hi I am trying to display the content of a database in the jsp page.. I would like the connection and processing of data to be in java file and only the display of the data will be included in the jsp page.

I am using tomcat server. I have ojdbc6.jar and jstl-1.2.jar on my WEB-INF/lib folder.

Kindly advise what I am missing.
Any idea would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

Here is the content of the java file.

### DBConn.java

```
public class DBConn extends HttpServlet {

    public void getData(HttpServletRequest request,
                        HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
                                                             ServletException {
        Connection connection = null;
        List dataList = new ArrayList();
        try {
            // Load the JDBC driver
            String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            Class.forName(driverName);

            // Create a connection to the database
            String serverName = "localhost";
            String portNumber = "1521";
            String sid = "xe";
            String url =
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" +
                sid;
            String username = "hr";
            String password = "hr";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");
            while (rset.next()) {
                dataList.add(rset.getInt("employee_id"));
                dataList.add(rset.getString("first_name"));
            }
            stmt.close();

        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // Could not find the database driver
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // Could not connect to the database
        }

        request.setAttribute("data", dataList);
        String strViewPage = "index.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher =
            request.getRequestDispatcher(strViewPage);
        if (dispatcher != null) {
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is the content of the jsp file.

### index.jsp

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="java.util.Iterator"%>
<%@page language="java" import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <table border="1" width="303">
        <tr>
            <td width="119"><b>Employee ID</b></td>
            <td width="168"><b>First Name</b></td>
        </tr>
        <%Iterator itr;%>
        <% List data = (List) request.getAttribute("data");
            for (itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        %>
        <tr>
            <td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>
            <td width="168"><%=itr.next()%></td>
        </tr>
        <%}%>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

### web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
version="3.0">

<!-- Config here. No taglibs! -->
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->

<!--web.xml code -->
<servlet>
<servlet-name>DBConn</servlet-name> 
<servlet-class>DBConn</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>DBConn</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/DBConn</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

### Output:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 26


23:             </tr>
24:             <%Iterator itr;%>
25:             <% List data = (List) request.getAttribute("data");
26:                 for (itr = data.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
27:             %>
28:             <tr>
29:                 <td width="119"><%=itr.next()%></td>


Stacktrace:
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:568)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
 root cause

  java.lang.NullPointerException
org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:88)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
```

Comment: Ideally put `stmt.close();` , `connection.close();`, `rset.close();` in `finally` block, so these will be executed regardless.

Comment: Your servlet is missing `doGet` or `doPost` service methods.

Comment: Wats the output ? Should we assume that your data is not visible on the page?

Comment: how getData method will be called??

Comment: sorry i forgot to put the output.. I have edited my post. thank you

Comment: What URL are you accessing in your browser when you get this error ?

Comment: @DavidLevesque no error now after I followed AVD's changes, but the data still not showing...

Comment: @Sujay right now the data don't display..

Answer (score 1):

You have to request `doGet` service method of *servlet* from web-browser (client) - `http://localhost:8084/DBConn` or `http://localhost:8084/webapp_context/DBConn`.

Create a POJO,

```
public class Employee{
   private Integer id;
   private String  name;
   //public constructors and
   //setter/getter
}
```

and change your servlet code,

```
public class DBConn extends HttpServlet{
  @Override
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, 
                    HttpServletResponse response) 
                       throws IOException, ServletException {
    Connection connection = null;
    Statement stmt=null;
    ResultSet rset=null;
    List<Employee> dataList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
    try {
        // Load the JDBC driver
        String driverName = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        Class.forName(driverName);

        // Create a connection to the database
        String serverName = "localhost";
        String portNumber = "1521";
        String sid = "xe";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + serverName + ":" + portNumber + ":" + sid;
        String username = "hr";
        String password = "hr";
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);

        stmt = connection.createStatement();
        rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from employees");
        while (rset.next()) {
            dataList.add(new Employee(rset.getInt("employee_id"),
                                      rset.getString("first_name"));
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // Could not find the database driver
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // Could not connect to the database
    } finally{
        if(rs!=null){
            try{ 
              rs.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) { /* */ }
        }
        if(stmt!=null){
            try{ 
              stmt.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) { /* */ }
        }
        if(connection !=null){
            try{ 
              connection.close();
            }catch(Exception ex) { /* */ }
        }
     }

     request.setAttribute("data", dataList);
     String strViewPage = "index.jsp";
     RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher(strViewPage);
      if (dispatcher != null) {
         dispatcher.forward(request, response);
      }
   }
}
```

and markup in `index.jsp`,

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:forEach var="employee" items="${data}">
  <br/> ${employee.id}  ${employee.name}
</c:forEach>
```

NOTE: Never create *Types(Classes)* in *default package*. You *must* have to specify the package name for POJO and Servlet sub-class.

Comment: Hi, I followed the changes you gave, the error was gone but the content of the table is still not showing.. query is valid :(

Comment: Mistake here! I've used `dataList` in JSP JSTL. Change it to `data`. Post edited.

Comment: still the same :( is my web.xml correct?